# For $A, B$ invertible matrices of the same order, is it true that $(A^T + B^T)^{-1} = (A^T)^{-1} + (B^T)^{-1}$?

Tags: matrices, inverse

If $A$ and $B$ are invertible matrices of the same order then is this statement true? Why?
$$(A^T + B^T)^{-1} = (A^T)^{-1} + (B^T)^{-1}$$

Comment: What's the role of transpose here? Any two matrices would have conveyed your question. (Since you are not using the properties of transpose of matrices) and neither are any properties of the matrices A and B such as symmetric or skew matrices given. Thus usage of transposes is unnecessary.

Comment: Consider $A=2I$ and $B=I$. I think that gives a counterexample.

Comment: Is it true even for 1-by-1 matrices?

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

Multiplying both sides of that equation by $A^T + B^T$ gives
$$I = (A^T + B^T)((A^T)^{-1} + (B^T)^{-1}) = 2I + B^T (A^T)^{-1} + A^T (B^T)^{-1},$$
which reduces to
$$A^T (B^T)^{-1} + B^T (A^T)^{-1} = -I$$
and that looks pretty dubious.

For an easy counterexample, consider $A=2I$ and $B = I$. Then $A=A^T$, $A^{-1} = \frac12 I$ and $B=B^T = B^{-1}$. So we have
$$A^T + B^T = 2I + I = 3I \qquad (A^T)^{-1} + (B^T)^{-1} = \tfrac12I + I = \tfrac32I,$$
and we see that the original statement fails.